# Can I make Wheatley (The Ap-Sap) talk all the time?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-spy

I just bought the Ap-Sap from backpack.tf. I love it dearly. However, Wheatley stops talking whenever I put him away (I am aware this is intended). Is there any way I can make him talk all the time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The only time you'll trigger [Wheatley's voice lines](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Wheatley_responses) when you switch to another weapon are:

- Sapper is attached to a building initially
- Sapper is in the middle of sapping a building
- Sapper has destroyed a building

If you really, really, really want him to continue talking, all you need to do is bind Previous Weapon and Next Weapon to your mouse wheel key, then just scroll through your loadout as a spy, allowing you have to Wheatley constantly spamming "Hello & Goodbye!" and "Okay.".

Comment: If that is the case, can I make him talk more regularly?

Comment: Find a reason to demo more buildings

Comment: You forgot the lines he makes when cloaking with him equipped

Answer (score 0):

There *is* an answer. Destroy more buildings with Wheatley to encourage Him, the Made-To-Be A Moron, show his mighty intelligence more frequently. Each time you sap a building or destroy one with a sapper, Wheatley talks.